# Function poles and divergence of series

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Yesterday I tried to calculate the residues of a function the way below, but soon I realized it won't work. Now I have a question about the poles of a function, and a series representing it.
$$z\in \Bbb C\setminus \{a\in \Bbb C\,|\,f(a)=1\} \Rightarrow 0\le |f(z)|\lt1\ $$ *Edit: the criteria above is not possible according to the anwser.* $$g(z)={1\over 1-f(z)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(z)^k$$
$g(z)$ diverges only when $f(z)=1$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane. So $g(z)$ is an infinite sum of function powers, and it has singularities at isolated points $a$ where $f(a)=1$.

However, since $f(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere: $$\oint _\gamma f(z)^k \,dz= 0$$ $$\oint_\gamma\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(z)^k\right)\,dz=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \oint _\gamma f(z)^k \,dz=0=\oint_\gamma g(z)\,dz$$

It is not always true according to the residue theorem.

**If I have a function** just like $g(x)$, **given as an infinite sum of holomorphic functions**, and I know where it diverges, but cannot get a closed form, **is it possible to calculate the residues of the poles**, or even can I say that a series have poles? (I am mainly interested in function like the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ above)

ps: I am still a high school student, only learned complex analysis by myself so probably I missed out some parts of the subject, but I cannot find anything about it.

Comment: The series expansion is invalid for $|f|\ge 1$ and the pole is at $f=1$.

Comment: I tought that since they are equal elsewhere, the series divergence point is the pole of the function, so they have the same residue there. It seems is not that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(z) = 1/(1-f(z))$ is holomorphic when $f(z) \ne 1$, but the series converges only when $|f(z)| < 1$.  In particular, because of the Maximum Modulus Theorem, if you have a closed contour $\gamma$ on which $|f(z)| < 1$, you will also have $|f(z)| < 1$ inside $\gamma$, and no singularities of $g$ there.  Thus you can never use the series to find a residue of $g$.

However, what is true is that if $p$ is a point where $f(p) = 1$, then
$f(z) = 1 + f'(p) (z - p) + O((z-p))^2$ as $z \to p$, so 
$$g(z) = \dfrac{1}{-f'(p)(z-p) + O((z-p)^2)} = -\dfrac{1}{f'(p) (z-p)} + O(1)$$
and thus the residue of $g$ at $p$ is $-1/f'(p)$.

Comment: I checked out that theorem...it seems that I need to find another way! Thanks for the answer, maybe I can reformulate my problem with that equation.